# IntelliJ android layout preview won't resolve resources out of nowhere

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I really don't know which information to put in here because the problem is so silly and ridiculous that I don't have a clue as to what might matter in order to understand it.
I was just working on a project yesterday night and after encountering a nasty android "bug"? (something to do with bitmaps disappearing from internal memory) I decided to shut down and keep on working today.
This morning I opened IntelliJ and suddenly the xml layout preview goes crazy:

> NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or
>   layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or:
>   Automatically add all missing attributes   Couldn't resolve resource
>   @string/app_name (46 similar errors not shown) "@dimen/logo_font_size"
>   in attribute "textSize" is not a valid format. (Edit) (25 similar
>   errors not shown)

It says that some layout_width or layout_height is missing, but none of these attributes is missing from any element. I know because the project won't build if there is such an error and I built the same project multiple times yesterday without any problems.
Additionally, every string, dimen and color resource cannot be resolved anymore even if the files are still there unchanged.

I did not pull from git or any other repository. I did not modify the project in any way in the meantime, and xmls have been left untouched. I did not install any android sdk component, tool or update in the meantime.

I already try to restart IntelliJ many times; I also tried to rebuild the project; but nothing works.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the layout XML.

Comment: It is irrelevant, it's the same error on every xml layout, regardless of the content. I would have to include tons of lines of xml in that case...

Comment: Try to see all problems and find a different error which is may be cause of all this mess.

Comment: Mmmhh, they seem all the same to me, where should I start?

Comment: I resolved those errors by invalidating IntelliJ caches but when I define new strings, they cannot be resolved...